# htaccess rewrite multi domain

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

i have a 2 domain website.

Basically, the 2 domains are for my multilanguage visitors. What i need is to rewrite `domain1.com/en/` to `domain2.com`, so that user will be able to see the english version of the site by just typeing the `domain2.com` in the address bar instead of `domain1.com/en/`.
Any tips?

and btw: i'm using php / apache..

EDIT:both domains point to the same hosting account...

tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines to your .htaccess file in the root folder of your website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/en [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry andrej it should be {HTTP_HOST} . Try now.

Comment: sorry man, but i just can't get it to work... and btw: shouldn't it be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/en/$1 [R,L] ?

Comment: Yea you are right. Btw, did u get that fixed by adding the parenthesis ?? If not try the edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use an .htaccess file for another domain.
I think you might need to play with the domain DNS settings.

Or use an iFrame like in 1996 :D

Comment: no but the other domain is parked on that one host... so both domains point to the one hosting account

Comment: Can't you point domain2.com directly to the subfolder ? I know I can do that with 1and1.com.
Otherwise an .htaccess file might work for what you want as its the same hosting account but I don't know how to do so sorry.